# Store binary file as a string inside my code

Tags: c, aix, dlopen

I'm creating a library to provide access to another library.
The library in question is a vendor, so not everyone should access this library.
One solution to do so is to put the library on a specific group (AIX) and then put everyone that can compile using it in the same group.
This solution don't works here because there are a lot of new people coming in and out, and the user that compiles (Its a process that do this operation) is not the same as the user that can access the code.
The solution i'm trying to archive is.
Every application have an pattern on their directory.
/Aplications/Group/...
So i can get the Group using the folder when the program runs.
What i am trying to do is.
Create a library that checks the directory and then loads the library using (loadAndInit) the dlopen function on AIX that already loads all the symbols, so i don't need the dlsym.
The problem is, i want to put the binary code of the library i want to load inside my source code.

WHY: Because if App -> Lib (Loads) -> Vendor, nothing can limit the developer from doing an link by hand or compiling by hand the App -> Vendor.
And the structure that call the compilation process cannot limit that.

What i have tried.

Convertlib

```
FILE* file=fopen("vendor.so", "rb");
int c;
do{
   c=getc(file);
   if(c > 0)
      printf("\\x%02x", c);
}while(c!=EOF);
```

Then i have a little script that puts the output of this file as a

```
char *lib=(char* (malloc(sizeof(char) * /* lib size */));
lib="/*output of the Convertlib*/
```

Then i try to load it using fmemopen, so i dont create a temporary file just a file descriptor inside my process area.

To load it i do

```
FILE* vendorLib=fmemopen(lib, /*libSize*/, "r");
char path[50];
sprintf("/proc/%d/fd/%d", getpid(), fileno(vendorLib));
loadAndInit(path, 0, "");
```

If i call directly a lib (i have it to test) and dont load using the hex formated library it works.
But as i converted my binary code to hex and i'm trying to load it, it dont work.
Should i convert back to load it on the memory and use it as an library again?

This seems the only solution to work with, as the library is a vendor i cannot change it and it is the only way i see to limit the access because we have here more than 1000 programmers

Comment: You can't store binary data as a string. Think about what would happen if the binary data contains a byte with the value zero (a.k.a. `'\0'`, a.k.a. the string terminator).

Comment: but if i put do the printf as \x it prints as \x0 so the \0 should work, another thing i did was to do an fwrite to my fmemopen and i tell it the size and to write as a binary file

Comment: Also remember that memory you allocate will not be marked as executable, and that the libraries initialization routines will not be executed (if you tell the kernel to mark the pages as executable) automatically, and that there are a lot of other things that the dynamic library loaded does when loading a library.

Comment: @Erbureth, if i use static linking how i will check on my library if i can or cannot provide the library, i should check if the user can or cannot load it. and i just have the shared from the vendor

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, i load it to an file pointer and give the path to the loadAndInit, so the SO will load it again (2 times) to the memory and load the link

Comment: It all depends on what `loadAndInit` does. Does it perform the same things the standard dynamic loaded does? You might rather want static linking when creating your library, and skip these problems completely.

Comment: I cannot do a static linking, because if i do so how will i block the access to the library

Comment: loadAndInit works with dlopen and dlsym

Comment: This approach smells quiet hacky. If you are in company with more then 1000 developers, there surly are some competent admins around which will help you work out a classical solution using various access rights provided by the OS. Go this way.

Comment: The problem is, a lot of people come in and go out, and because the C++ is a language that the company don't want to provide support the OS team will not do that. the solution should be create an group and everyone be that can use the library have access to that, but the compilation process is called by the same user, so i cannot limit the access by the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using

printf("\x%02x", thechar);

Inside the getc loop

So i wrote it inside a memcpy then i copy to the memory so the binary file is stored as HEX data.

Works perfectly